# Convert a "by" object to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I'm using the "by" function in R to chop up a data frame and apply a function to different parts, like this:

```
pairwise.compare <- function(x) {
Nright <- ...
Nwrong <- ...
Ntied <- ...
return(c(Nright=Nright, Nwrong=Nwrong, Ntied=Ntied))
}
Z.by <- by(rankings, INDICES=list(rankings$Rater, rankings$Class), FUN=pairwise.compare)
```

The result (Z.by) looks something like this:

```
: 4 
: 357 
Nright Nwrong Ntied
     3      0     0
------------------------------------------------------------
: 8 
: 357 
NULL
------------------------------------------------------------
: 10 
: 470 
Nright Nwrong Ntied
     3      4     1 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
: 11 
: 470 
Nright Nwrong Ntied
    12      4     1
```

What I would like is to have this result converted into a data frame (with the NULL entries not present) so it looks like this:

```
  Rater Class Nright Nwrong Ntied
1     4   357      3      0     0
2    10   470      3      4     1
3    11   470     12      4     1
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using ddply in the plyr package instead of by. It handles the work of adding the column to your dataframe.

Comment: It's surprising that this is the accepted and top-rated answer without any sort of code showing how to solve with the ddply function. This should be a comment in my opinion.

Answer (score 20):

The `by` function returns a list, so you can do something like this:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", by(x, column, mean)))
```

Comment: That almost does what I want, I get a data frame with the Nright, Nwrong and Ntied columns, but it doesn't produce the Rater and Class columns.

Comment: I would suggest changing your `pairwise.compare` function to return those two fields.  Otherwise you will have to use an `lapply` routine (or `plyr`) to get both the list names and values (which is an extra step).

Comment: It appears that plyr is actually a simpler solution than by in this case, I just didn't know about that package before.

Comment: This used for me but started getting "error in do.call("rbind", X) : second argument must be a list" . What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but for anyone who searches for this topic:

```
analysis = by(...)
data.frame(t(vapply(analysis,unlist,unlist(analysis[[1]]))))
```

`unlist()` will take an element of a `by()` output (in this case, `analysis`) and express it as a named vector.
`vapply()` does unlist to all the elemnts of `analysis` and outputs the result. It requires a dummy argument to know the output type, which is what `analysis[[1]]` is there for. You may need to add a check that analysis is not empty if that will be possible.
Each output will be a column, so `t()` transposes it to the desired orientation where each analysis entry becomes a row.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you happen to have mixed types in your data.frame (like characters in one column and numerics in another), because it relies on `vapply`. In this specific case, Shane's solution above works perfectly well though.

Answer (score 3):

This expands upon Shane's solution of using rbind() but also adds columns identifying groups and removes NULL groups - two features which were requested in the question. By using base package functions, no other dependencies are required, e.g., plyr.

```
simplify_by_output = function(by_output) {
    null_ind = unlist(lapply(by_output, is.null))  # by() returns NULL for combinations of grouping variables for which there are no data. rbind() ignores those, so you have to keep track of them.
    by_df = do.call(rbind, by_output)  # Combine the results into a data frame.
    return(cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(by_output))[!null_ind, ], by_df))  # Add columns identifying groups, discarding names of groups for which no data exist.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do

```
x = by(data, list(data$x, data$y), function(d) whatever(d))
array(x, dim(x), dimnames(x))
```

Comment: And then you have an `matrix`/`array`, but not a `data.frame`.